# how to set and update a database filed to random numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers, set

hello i have a table where data is stored, this table consist of a field called tnx_ref, i am trying to automatically update this field with random numbers anytime i update my table
this is what i tried,

```
$tnx_ref = $_SESSION['genref'];




$sql = "UPDATE transactions ".
      "SET tnx_ref = '62323232'".
    "WHERE id = $id";
```

from the snippet above i have updated the value of that particular field "tnx_ref with "62323232", but now i want to make it different random numbers for every time i update.

how can i possible do this, any1 done such

Comment: every record gets a different random number, or every record gets the SAME random number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can dou it using mysql
(for generating 2-digit random numbers between 10 and 99 for example):

```
$sql = "UPDATE transactions ".
      "SET tnx_ref = FLOOR(10 + (RAND() * 90))".
    "WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: thanks alot, i can set every record rand between 1 2 3 by Update trips set driver_id = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 3))

Answer (score 1):

Use random number in php:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

```
$random_number = rand();
$sql = "UPDATE transactions ".
       "SET tnx_ref = '$random_number'".
       "WHERE id = $id";
```

You can also define, how many digits you want by this: `rand(5, 15);` (It'll give you random number between 5 to 15 digits).